# Vlookup range returns date format for few rows and general format for few rows despite the source being same

Tags: excel, vba, date, vlookup

I am writing a code to vlookup dates for diff numbers. But it returns date for few rows and few other rows are in general format.

[image]

For the registration date, few rows are in general format (those that are visible) and few in date format (those that are as #######). Also the ones in date format have their days and months swapped. Like 09-01-2024 is entered as 01-09-2024.

The source format for all rows is exactly the same.

I cannot trace why vba is treating some entries differently.

Tried datevalue, tried changing the source to all date format, tired cdate function, tried text function...nothing worked

Comment: Please create a [reprex], sharing all relevant code.

Comment: Try to increase column width

Comment: It's not treating some entries differently - you mention that days and months are being swapped, so any registration date with the day >12 will fail to convert to a valid date. So your problem probably is that your regional settings tell Excel to assume dates are in US format ("mm-dd-yyyy"), but your dates are actually in international format ("dd-mm-yyyy").

Comment: @Paul how do I change the excel settings?

Comment: You would do that in the Windows settings, but it affects all applications. Probably easier to explicitly parse the date string in VBA, using `Split()` and `Dateserial()`

Comment: Split and DateSerial also didnt work. The issue is still impacting only few rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

L = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basefile").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To L
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basefile").Range("H" & i).Value = Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basefile").Range("B" & i).Value, S1.Range("B2:AAX40000"), 43, False)
Next i

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).